# Is there a way to input something like 1*10**2?

Tags: python

what the title says

when i try to input a number in the form of a scientific notation like 1*10**12 in this code:

```
h = float(input.('enter the value of [H+]: '))
```

I get this error

```
h = float(input('enter the value of [H+]: '))
ValueError: could not convert string to float: '1*10**12'
```

Comment: That's not a legal `float` literal, but `1e12` is.

Comment: You did fine. Don't fret.

Comment: Instead of including apologies (as they detract from your question), you should review the [Tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: [`eval`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#eval) will work in your specific case, but you should not do that, as it will evaluate any expression from the input. You should think again and accept a different type of notation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The standard syntax is to use little `e` to denote a float literal with a power of 10 exponent, e.g. `1e2` is `1*(10**2)` in a floating point representation

Answer (score 1):

Just enter "1e22" and convert it with float. "1e22" is python notation for 1x10^22.